NeoForge Minecraft Modding Workflow Failing with Gradle Error: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'
My problem description
I recently resumed Minecraft modding using NeoForge after a short break. However, I'm now encountering a Gradle error during my workflow, both locally on my PC and in my GitHub CI/CD setup. The error initially appeared on my PC, and I fixed it temporarily by reinstalling the JDK. However, it reappeared later, affecting my workflow setup on GitHub as well as my local development environment.
The error details
Here is the error message I am encountering:
(View Full (Github) Error Log),
(View Full (local) Error log)
What I've Tried

Reinstalling JDK: This temporarily resolved the issue on my PC.
Verified Environment Setup:: NeoForge version: 21.1.76, JDK version: Adoptium Temurin jdk-21.0.5.11-hotspot, Gradle version: 8.9.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. It worked perfectly yesterday but suddenly started failing again today.
My Environment

OS: Windows 11 (version: 23H2, OS Build: 22631.4460)
NeoForge Version:21.1.76 (Parchment minecraft ver: 1.21.1, parchment mappings: 2024.11.13)
Java Development Kit (JDK): Adoptium Temurin jdk-21.0.5.11-hotspot
Gradle Version: 8.9.
Github workflow:

name: Build

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          fetch-tags: true

      - name: Setup JDK 21
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v4

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build --stacktrace --info --warning-mode=all

Thanks in advance for any insight.
